# using size of scatter points to weight line of best fit in matlab

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to use the size (s) of the points to 'weight' the line of best fit?

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
y = [2 4 5 3 4];
s = [10 15 20 2 5];
scatter(x,y,s)
hold on
weight = s;
p = polyfit(x,y,1); %how do I take into account the size of the points?
f = polyval(p,x);
plot(x,f,'-r')
```

Comment: You could use wieghted-least-square fit. More info with examples about it for matlab is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98657).

Comment: Thanks @Marcin - having had a look over this documentation, I can't figure out how to use the function. I'd assume someting like, `a = lscov(x,y,s)` to obtain the coordinates? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user2861089 I expanded Marcin's suggestion. Does this help you?

Answer (score 1):

Using Marcin's suggestion, you can incorporate `lscov` into `polyfit`. As the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) explains, polynomial fitting is done by computing the [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) `V` of `x`, and then executing `p = V\y`. This is the standard formalism of any least-squares solution, and lends itself to weighted-least-squares in MATLAB through [`lscov`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lscov.html).

Taking your `x`, `y` and `weight` vectors, instead of calling `polyfit(x,y,n)` you can do the following:

```
% Construct Vandermonde matrix. This code is taken from polyfit.m
V(:,n+1) = ones(length(x),1,class(x));
for j = n:-1:1
   V(:,j) = x.*V(:,j+1);
end
% Solve using weighted-least-squares
p = lscov(V,y,weight);
```

You can even go one step further, and modify polyfit.m itself to include this functionality, or add another function polyfitw.m if you are not inclined to modify original MATLAB functions. Note however that `polyfit` has some more optional outputs for structure, computed using QR decomposition as detailed in the documentation. Generalization of these outputs to the weighted case will require some more work.

Comment: This code didn't work for me until I made the following changes - line 4: `V(:,j) = x'.*V(:,j+1);`; line 7: `p = lscov(V,y',weight);` but now I believe it works. Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

```
x = (1:10)';
y = (3 * x + 5) + rand(length(x),1)*5;
w =  ones(1,length(y));

A = [x ones(length(x),1)];
p = lscov(A,y,w);

plot(x,y,'.');
hold on
plot(x,p(1)*x + p(2),'-r');
```

Comment: You should explain your answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: I'll try:lscov solves the overdetermined linear system Ap = y + error, where w is a vector of weights for each x. So you are solving p(1)x(1) + p(2) = y(1);  p(1)x(2) + p(2) = y(2) ...p(1)x(n) + p(2) = y(n).